# Return String result type from Struts2. Problem with encoding

Tags: xml, struts2, xslt

I've written an action that returns a string. The returned string is an xml-string.
E.g. I'd like to return this xml, but I receive this UTF-8 format: `&lt;request&gt;&lt;id&gt;6&lt;/id&gt;`

This is the xslt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="result">
        <response>
            <receiver>
                <xsl:value-of select="retString"/>
            </receiver>
        </response>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And struts file:

```
<action name="retString" method="retString" 
        class="it.whereareyou.action.RequestAction">
    <result type="xslt" name="success">
        <param name="stylesheetLocation">request.xslt</param>
        <param name="matchingPattern">^/result/[^/*]$</param>
    </result>
    <result name="error">error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

The action is invoked and the getter and setter methods are wellformat... The string is returned, but in this format `&lt;request&gt;` instead of `<request>`.

Comment: Have you tried doing some googling?  Seems like you need to tell struts you want a raw output stream.  Do a search for "struts raw output".  The hit http://www.javahowto.net/struts2/automatic-raw-data-output-struts-2/ seems to provide the information you need to solve the problem.

Comment: I tried this with property and other tags by setting escape attribute to true/false accordingly.